# WalletConnect always creates new pairing when connecting

Tags: ethereum, web3js, wallet-connect

I want to connect my dapp with WalletConnect, but I want to create only one pairing for my application. For testing purpose I use WalletConnect [demo wallet](https://react-wallet.walletconnect.com/walletconnect) and as I can see every time I create connection, new pairing appears:

[WalletConnect demo wallet with multiple, same pairings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aXcw.png)

I want to have one pairing only.

When user first time visits my dapp, I connect to WalletConnect using UniversalProvider (without topic - topic is undefined yet).

```js
import UniversalProvider from "@walletconnect/universal-provider";

const ethereumProvider = await UniversalProvider.init({
            projectId: projectId
        });

let requiredNamespaces = {
                namespaces: {
                    eip155: {
                        methods: [
                            "eth_sendTransaction",
                            "eth_signTransaction",
                            "eth_sign",
                            "personal_sign",
                            "eth_signTypedData",
                        ],
                        chains: [chainId],
                        events: ["chainChanged", "accountsChanged"],
                    }
                },
            };
const session = await ethereumProvider.connect(requiredNamespaces);
```

So session is established so I store session object and topicId in local storage:

```js
// after this I store session object and session.topic in local storage
window.localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session));
window.localStorage.setItem('topicId', JSON.stringify(session.topic));
```

Now user decided to disconnect session:

```js
await ethereumProvider.disconnect();

// I remove session, but topic is still stored
window.localStorage.removeItem('session');
```

And now user decided to connect to my dapp again:

```js
const topicId = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('topicId'));
let requiredNamespaces = {
                namespaces: {
                    eip155: {
                        methods: [
                            "eth_sendTransaction",
                            "eth_signTransaction",
                            "eth_sign",
                            "personal_sign",
                            "eth_signTypedData",
                        ],
                        chains: [chainId],
                        events: ["chainChanged", "accountsChanged"],
                        pairingTopic: topicId

                    }
                },
            };
const session = await ethereumProvider.connect(requiredNamespaces);
```

And now the problem - the new pairing will be added to wallet, instead of using the old one.

I don't know if this is proper way of handling WalletConnect session and pairing.

Do I do something wrong? Maybe I shouldn't disconnect this way? Is this a WalletConnect issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using pairingTopic param in the wrong place.
It should be at the same nesting level of 'namespaces'.
As can be seen in [walletconnect's monorepo](https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo), the object passed in to the 'connect' method of UniversalProvider implements this interface:

```
export interface ConnectParams {
  namespaces?: NamespaceConfig;
  optionalNamespaces?: NamespaceConfig;
  sessionProperties?: ProposalTypes.Struct["sessionProperties"];
  pairingTopic?: string;
  skipPairing?: boolean;
}
```